# Bad to have undervoltage?

Tags: raspbian

I constantly have the yellow light showing on the top right of the screen.
Which means that the pi doesn't get enough power. I have a 5 volt and 2,1 amp adapter. Is this bad in anyway or could the pi break? I'm using It for a bot on google chrome which bets automatically for me on a cs go betting site.

Comment: The damage from under-powering usually shows by corruption of the SD card. This can result in file corruption, which may lead into very strange results, bad data, or even an unbootable RPi. In essence, yep, it's bad.

Comment: This may be a bit of circular reasoning but if it was a good thing would they design a system that obtrusively overlays an icon on the display. Take some of your winnings and by a better power supply and cable.

Answer (score 4):

In contrast to other comments, the Pi will run quite happily with voltages down to about 4V. The SOC and SD Card run from 3.3V supplied by an on-board regulator, but USB peripherals may be affected. Not that I recommend this, as it is a symptom that something is wrong.

You don't say which model Pi; they vary. As you have a "yellow light showing on the top right of the screen" (actually meant to be rainbow - warning) you obviously have an old OS, and may have an old Pi. There was also a over-temperature warning, but I have never seen it. This too has been replaced by a thermometer icon.

You should use a proper supply **AND** cable. See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Answer (score 3):

Under-powering a Raspberry Pi is quite bad.

Usually, symptoms will start showing up with usage, due to the SD card becoming corrupt. This can happen systematically slowly over time, or very rapidly depending on where the corruption on the card occurs.

The results can be lost data, corrupt files or at worst, an un-bootable Pi.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if I should get a better power supply or not but I'll get one now!!

Answer (score 1):

PI3B AND PI3B+ are very picky about undervoltage. Voltages on the input must be over 5V otherwise it shows the undervoltage symbol. It still works fine but at almost half of the processing speed.

Comment: This is factually incorrect! The CPU voltages are unaffected until the voltage is so low the regulator drops out - processing is unaffected. The dropout is 4.63±0.07V. NOTE the Pi3B+ has a different regulator and the  Pi3B circuitry is identical to Pi2, PiB+

Comment: It is just an observation on a Rpi 3B and a Rpi's 3B+ running the same code. My assumption is that the undervoltage warning has the same effect as the overheating warning, the processor speed is reduced! It does not drop out, just runs slower. It takes about twice the time to run the same code. And 4.9V measured on the 5V GPIO pin is sufficient to light up the undervoltage warning.